# Is there a way to have parse allow Facebook Logins?

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform, ios9

This is all using Parse 1.8.2 framework

Working on my app update for iOS 9 and came across an issue with the Parse framework, specifically, logging in with Facebook.  When attempting I get a popup that says Login Failed com.facebook.sdk error 5.  In the console log I get:

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
2015-09-14 23:19:59.036 iPrayed[2649:125172] Failed to log in...Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x7fc622827810>, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?,
```

I handle login to facebook with:

```
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];

        // Send request to Facebook
        [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *userCloud, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                // result is a dictionary with the user's Facebook data
                NSDictionary *userData = userCloud;
                NSLog(@"%@", userData);
                NSString *facebookID = userData[@"id"];

                PFUser *me = [PFUser currentUser];
                NSString *objective = [me objectId];
                PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
                [currentInstallation setValue:objective forKey:@"usersObjectId"];
                me[@"fbId"] = facebookID;

                [currentInstallation saveInBackground];

                me[@"additional"] = userCloud.name;


                // me[@"lastName"] = userCloud.last_name;

                me[@"email"] = userData[@"email"];


                UIImage *theImage = [[FBSingleton sharedInstance] userImage];
                [me saveEventually];

                // download the image from Facebook and then save it into the singleton
                NSURL *pictureURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=normal&return_ssl_resources=1", facebookID]];

                NSLog(@"Picture URL%@", pictureURL);
                NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pictureURL];

                // Run network request asynchronously
                [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                       completionHandler:
                 ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                     if (connectionError == nil && data != nil) {
                         // Set the image in the header imageView
                         //  self.headerImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                         UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

                         NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                         NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.png"];
                         [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
                         NSUserDefaults *testDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.316apps.iPrayed"];
                         [testDefaults setObject:me.username forKey:@"username"];
                         [testDefaults setObject:me.password forKey:@"password"];

                         [testDefaults synchronize];

                         FBSingleton *sharedSingleton = [FBSingleton sharedInstance];
                         sharedSingleton.userImage = image;
                     }
                 }];

            }
        }];
```

What's going on with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've run into the app transport security feature in iOS9. You need to whitelist Facebook, as described here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9